# Python replacing empty list in a list with a string to avoid IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

I wrote this code and it works to fine to scrape H1 tags from a list of websites. There are some particular websites that don't have an H1 so an empty list is returned and it gives IndexError: list index out of range, and stops the script.

```
    list_flagged = df['Websites'].to_list()

    new_flagged_list = []

    for site in list_flagged:                                                                
        quote_page = requests.get(site, headers=random_header)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(quote_page.text, 'html.parser')
        h1tag = soup.find_all('h1')
        titles = [(h1.get_text()).strip() for h1 in h1tag] 
        appended = new_flagged_list.append(titles)
        print('appended')
        if new_flagged_list == ['']:
            ['x']    
        new = [x[0] for x in new_flagged_list]
```

I tried with if new_flagged_list == ['']: to change an empty row but still the error appears. I don't understand anyway why

```
    new = [x[0] for x in new_flagged_list]
```

ignores an empty list in a list with list index error. Why it cannot keep an empty list?

How can I change the empty list in a list with whatever string to avoid the error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if not new_flagged_list:
       print("do task here")
```

In the above code you are checking if list is empty or not

Answer (score 0):

I couln't understand what you tried to do with

```
if new_flagged_list == ['']:
            ['x']
```

You don't assign anything to a variable here. You can also try:

```
if titles:
    appended = new_flagged_list.append(titles)
```

so that you only append when titles is not empty.

Comment: thanks, but I would like to keep either an empty list (row eventually) or to fill it with a string, because on each website excel row I want to have the corresponding h1 tag scraped

Comment: Then, new_flagged_list = ['x'] might solve your problem instead of only ['x'], since you do not achieve anything with the line containing only ['x']

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
        if new_flagged_list == ['']:
            ['x']
```

don't do anything, aside from creating and immediately destroying a list containing only 'x'. I guess you want:

`new_flagged_list = ['x']`